# Stop a 2nd Android Emulator opening up

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi I'm creating an Android app but am quite new to it so am having a few problems.  I'm using the emulator to run the app.  But the problem I'm having is that when I try to debug the app its starting up a 2nd emulator which doesn't have my SQLite database showing in the File Explorer.  Has anyone any idea how I can:

1. Stop the 2nd Emulator from opening up or
2. Get it to show the database in File Explorer when it does?

I can't debug the App until its sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the emulator you want to run for the project by `right-clicking on your project` **-->** `Run As..` **-->** `Run Configuration`**-->** go to `Target Tab`, put a `V` next to your desired `AVD`, `Apply` your settings and `Run` the project.

Next time when you press the run button in your eclipse environment this will be the AVD that will be used for this project.

**Update:**

another option would be under the `Target tab` just set the `Always prompt to pick device`.
that way you will be prompted before running the application.

**Update #2:**

when the windows for choosing a devices opens but you can't see your current device what you should do is to open your `command prompt`(`CMD`) and type: `adb kill-server` and then `adb logcat` to start the server. you current device will be updated in the device chose window.

Comment: Yeah I have done that, but if I already have an Emulator open (usually opens with '5554'), when I go to run or debug the project aggin it opens up a 2nd emulator ('5556').  That would be no problem but unfortunately the 2nd emulator doesn't appear to have my database attached to it or at least it doesn't show in up in File Explorer.  Any help be great cheers.

Comment: Cheers Emil tried that but I don't think thats the problem either, as I only have the one device in there.  The problem is it keeps opening different versions of the same device e.g '5554', '5556', '5558' and so on.  I've no idea why its happening.

Comment: Ok, let us know if you still have a problem, and mark this answer as accepted if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue some time ago with the File Explorer, try with this plugin: [sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/).

Comment: Thanks mate, its not a problem of not seeing the data though, I had that problem already.  I downloaded 'SQLite Database Browser' to display the data in the database.  Its more a problem of the database not showing up at all in file explorer when the 2nd emulator starts up.  Thanks for your help though.